# Order Select Option by value alphabetically

Tags: java, salesforce, apex

I have a SelectOption[] populated by a API values, and I need to order by values, not key. The order need to be [0-9-A-Z]. Also, I need to fix a value in the first position, the 'Select Description' value. I tried somethings and not working. Can someone help me please? I'm loosing my mind with this problem.

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that the SelectOption compareTo() method that can be used for any other Custom Classes for implementing Custom Sorting can't be modified in this case.

I suggest you use the workaround that is suggested here: https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=906F00000008zlJIAQ

The idea basically is to first create a value for the SelectOption that uses a concatenation of the label with the value first in order to use the sort() method with the labels. Once the list is ordered by the use of the sort() method, you can just revert the concatenation but now you will end up with a sorted list.

Another approach would be to define your own CustomSelectOption class and implement the compareTo() method using the label instead of the value (https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_list_sorting_sobject.htm). Then you can easily convert a sorted list of CustomSelectOption to a SelectOption one.

Answer (score -1):

```
public static List<SelectOption> sortSelectOptionList(List<SelectOption> source)
{
    List<string> sortable = new  LIst<string>();
    for(SelectOption so: source)
    {
        // replace blank with '_!' so we know the final split will have two components
        sortable.Add((string.isblank(so.getLabel())?'_!':so.getLabel()) + '@!@' + (string.isblank(so.getValue())?'_!':so.getValue()));
    }
    // sort the list
    sortable.sort();
    List<SelectOption> targetList = new  List<SelectOption>();
    // split the value/name components and re create the list
    for(string s: sortable)
    {
            targetList.Add(new  SelectOption(s.split('@!@')[1].replace('_!',''), s.split('@!@')[0].replace('_!','')));
     
    }
    return targetList;
}
```

Please refer below link for more details.

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_list_sorting_sobject.htm

I hope you find the above solution helpful. If it does, please mark it as the Best Answer to help others too.

Thanks and Regards,
Suraj Tripathi

Comment: Thank you! I tried to implemented like this, calling the class that I created for this method: SelectOptionSorter.sortSelectOptionList(sList); But not working :((((